# Orden en una expresión aritmética

Tags: java

Una curiosidad, si tengo:

```
r  = (int) (Math.sqrt(a) * 7.5 + b / c);
```

En el libro pone que primero se ejecuta el método estático sqrt pero yo pienso que puede ejecutarse ese método y luego el producto por 7.5, o primero el b/c.

vosotros qué opináis?

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a evaluar la expresión que tienes dentro de los paréntesis..
**`(Math.sqrt(a) * 7.5 + b / c)`**

---

Primeramente, tenemos a **Math.sqrt()** que nos devuelve un valor de tipo **double**, y tenemos que verlo así, como un **número**.

Después tenemos los siguientes **operadores:** `*  +  /`.

- La siguiente tabla nos muestra el orden de precedencia de los
  operadores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**-** Como podemos ver, la multiplicación y la división se encuentra en la misma altura de precedencia, y la suma se encuentra una escala por debajo. Por lo tanto, la suma será lo último que se ejecute. Podríamos verlo así 'con paréntesis' para verlo más claro.

```
(Math.sqrt(a) * 7.5) + (b / c)
```

Y a igual precedencia, se ejecutará la operación situada más a la izquierda en la expresión.

---

Te dejo una expresión parecida y más sencilla para verlo más claro, con el resultado.

```
(3 * 4 + 2 / 2) = 13
```

Saludos!.

Comment: Pero como en el caso de (3 * 4 + 2 / 2) = 13 el compilador a priori no sabe si ejecutar primero el 3*4 o el 2/2 no?

Comment: Ante igualdad de prioridad, siempre ejecuta antes el de la izquierda, osea el producto o multiplicación en este caso.